# Is there a mixed data structure between array and JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

A team handed out their project to mine, in which I saw something strange. 
They first declared a variable as an array:

```
private myvariable: Array<any> = [];
```

But then in the code, they were using it as an object, doing things like:

```
myvariable['key'] = { 'prop': 'val' }
```

This ends up evaluated as something strange:

```
[key: {...}]
```

Does someone know how to explain this data structure?

Comment: I don't what you consider to be "strange" about this.  This is an array with an element keyed 'key' which contains a hash.  Perfectly normal-looking to me.

Comment: see http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html.  Javascript arrays are just a subclass of object with a magic length property, a custom string coercion method, and a few other extras like `forEach`, `push`, etc. The Index operator (`[x]`) is actually unchanged from a regular object, and array keys behave mostly like strings in any case.

Comment: Also keep this in mind:  "JSON is an *encoding."*  It is a standard way to represent a complex data structure as a string, in a way that can be sent and received using AJAX.  Like all languages, PHP provides a way to encode and decode these strings to-and-from data structures.

Comment: @MikeRobinson It's something I don't see everyday, so that's why that's strange to me. Not everyone has the same level of knowledge about JavaScript.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner thanks for your comment, it was a good read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Array is basically a JavaScript Object and can have properties and methods associated with it, just like a "pure" object. It being an Array will affect its behaviour when it comes to methods like `.toString()` or when it is being converted by `JSON.stringify()`. Its properties will *not* be found in the JSON representation.

You can visualise it's properties by casting (`Object.assign()`-ing) it to an object like in:

```
var array=[1,2,3];
array.key='hello';
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.assign({},array)));
// {"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"key":"hello"}
```

This will show the array as an object (the index numbers will appear like string property names with their associated values).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand it now!